# Angular http post request got code status 500

Tags: angular, rest, ionic-framework

I am trying to acces a REST api service from my Ionic app.
When I use post method, I can notice that de data are sent to the database (the object has been successfuly modified), however I recieve a code status 500.
Could you explain to me why? Is it possible to have the data modified successfuly where we got this kind of code status?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The 500 Internal Server Error is a very general HTTP status code that means something has gone wrong on the web site's server but the server could not be more specific on what the exact problem

There are some stuff you can do to find out what's the problem such as :

- Clear your browser cache
- Delete your browser's cookies
- Check out your API service log

Many browser error messages are similar to the 500 Internal Server Error message because they're all server-side errors, like 502 Bad Gateway, 503 Service Unavailable, and 504 Gateway Timeout.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @vala so the problem is probably coming from the api server side?

Comment: absolutely my friend

Comment: Thanks for your help!